# odometry using camera or kinect

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, visual-odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there packages on groovy that can provide odometry using camera or kinect? I tried laser_scan_matcher but was not able to build it from source. Please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196999/odometry-using-camera-or-kinect/) by [Bhargav](https://answers.ros.org/users/5029/bhargav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are many out there .These are some of the state-of-the-art and should give good results

**Kinect :**

RGBD SLAM

CCNY_RGBD

DVO (Dense Visual  Odometry)

demo_rgbd http://wiki.ros.org/demo_rgbd

**Camera alone**

LSD-SLAM (http://vision.in.tum.de/research/lsdslam) (Latest and should give very good results) (camera alone)

PTAM (many enhancements should be available out there) (a bit old)

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2014-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bhargav](https://answers.ros.org/users/5029/bhargav/) on 2014-11-10**:
thank you!..that was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try [fovis_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/fovis_ros). It's a visual odometer that can use stereo cameras or a kinect.

If not, [viso2_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/viso2_ros) can use either mono or stereo cameras to produce odometry.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2014-11-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bhargav](https://answers.ros.org/users/5029/bhargav/) on 2014-11-10**:
thank you!